# Sort results by relevance using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am running a simple search on an intranet site and I would like to sort the results by relevance to the query.

Here's what I have so far.

```
var customer = from c in db.Customer
               select c;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    customer = customer.Where(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.CustomerID).Trim().Equals(searchString)
    || c.CustomerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
    || SqlFunctions.SoundCode(c.CustomerName.ToUpper()) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(searchString.ToUpper()));
}

switch (s)
{
    case "NameDesc":
        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(c => c.CustomerName);
        break;
    default:
        customer = customer.OrderBy(c => c.CustomerName);
        break;
}
```

As I am using Sounds Like it is returning additional possible matches, which is useful to me, however I would like the closest match to what has been type in the search box to appear first in the results.

Is this possible to do using a query on the OrderBy or do I need to use FullText searching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a weight parameter to the queries:

```
customersLevel1 = customer
.Where(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.CustomerID).Trim().Equals(searchString))
.Select(c => new { cust = c, weight = 1});

customersLevel2 = customer
.Where(c => c.CustomerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
.Select(c => new { cust = c, weight = 2});

customersLevel3 = customer
.Where(c => SqlFunctions.SoundCode(c.CustomerName.ToUpper()) == SqlFunctions.SoundCode(searchString.ToUpper()))
.Select(c => new { cust = c, weight = 3});
```

Then to retrieve the data with one query to the DB you can use Union():

```
var result = (customersLevel1)
             .Union(customersLevel2)
             .Union(customersLevel3)
             .OrderBy(c => c.weight)
             .Select(c => c.cust);
```